# SqlBulkCopy unusual TimeOut Error

Tags: sqlbulkcopy, timeoutexception

I have a SqlBulkCopy operation that is taking data from an MS-Access 2007 database (via OleDbConnection) and using SqlBulkCopy to transfer that data to a SQL Server database.  This has previously been working and continues to work for one MS-Access database, but not the other.

I get the error message:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

It is hard to believe it is a timeout ast the oledbCommand.CommandTimeout = 0 the sqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0 and on either side (MS-Access and SQL Server the timeouts have now been set to 0).

Are there other issues/exceptions that the above error message could be hiding?  Is there a way to determine what the base cause of a sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer exception is (there doesn't appear to be any inner exceptions etc...)

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was that there were dates being transfered and some of those dates were invalid for SQL, but valid in Access.  For whatever reason this was presenting as a Timeout rather than "invalid date/time" - though if you reduce the data being transfered to a handful of rows (200) rather than the full transfer (500,000) it reports as invalid date/time ... curious.